# Create poll similar to Facebook poll

Tags: web-apps, survey

I need to create a poll for my users. Basically they will enter the responses and vote for them. I need something really similar to Facebook polls, but can't use that as they removed the option to use it on a FB page.

I will add one or two basic answers, and users can add and vote for more options. I need that every option added by a user to be visible in the poll, and ready to be voted on by other users.

Do you know anything that will work for me? I need a web app, I can self host or pay an existing service.

Comment: Thanks, integrated that with your question (note that you can always [edit] your post to improve/correct). As for "pay an existing service", you might wish to name a budget (how much you're willing to spend at max). // While waiting for answers, please take a look at [these Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=web-app+for+poll+survey). You might even be able to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then. [18 Awesome Survey & Poll Apps](http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/18-awesome-survey-poll-apps/) sounds like a good starter :)

Comment: *I need something really similar to Facebook polls* Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software and [edit] your question accordingly.